# Adding UISearchBar with Scope button as subview to UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I want to add UISearchbar with two scoop button to my UIView. i do not want to either navigation or table view.
when user open model view page from sheet comes up with Search option and rest. when user click on Search button scoop button to be visible.
i tried to do but i am not getting desire result.[image: Image after Search]

[image: Image after Cancel]

how to remove Background of scope button, i have removed uisearchbar, similar way i do not want white background for button. is it possible. showsScopeBar i am making FALSE still background can be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Background image of scope buttons just try :

```
 Class segmentedControlBackgroundView = NSClassFromString(@"_UISegmentedControlBackgroundView");
    for(UIView *view in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]){
            for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
                if ([subview isKindOfClass:segmentedControlBackgroundView]) {
                    subview.hidden = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```